# Restart app at specific view or page

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, restart

I wrote a simple iPad app in Xcode 4. When I exit the app then go back into the app, it starts on the last page that I was at before exit. How do I have the app restart at a designated page at each restart?

Comment: do you mean exit like _terminate_ the applicaton, or you mean exit like the application _becomes inactive_?

Comment: Terminate yes. I want the app to always start at the main page/main view. When I exit the app, pressing the home button, it takes me back to the last view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in your `AppDelegate.m` file for the method `applicationDidBecomeActive:` (below). This gets called whenever your app becomes active - either through being launched or through being returned from the background. This is the event that you would use to restore the state of you app - but the specifics would depend on how your app is setup.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while 
    //the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background,
    //optionally refresh the user interface.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Any examples so app will start from main screen/main view. Thanks

Comment: How your app sets itself up from a fresh launch - that is what you want to do to reset it.